# spring xsd:element name to bean class mapping

Tags: spring, xsd, spring-integration, spring-bean

In spring integration and other spring derivatives, xml elements(tags) are used to simplify spring configuration files by defining element to bean class mapping.

I am interested to know where the mapping between the xsd:element and bean class is actually defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything goes to **NamespaceHandler**
Here is a manual: [Extensible XML authoring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html)

Note: in the link above **/current/** path always goes to current Spring release

Comment: May be I was not clear. My question is who this tag <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory../> gets translated into this bean org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory or someother bean? Where is such mapping defined? It does not exist in http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd, then where?

Comment: The answer is correct, but maybe a bit broad. There is a `NamespaceHandler` for the integration namespace (actually for each namespace). For this one it is the 'IpNamespaceHandler', for each element there is (generally) a `BeanDefinitionParser`. For the one you mentioned that is the `TcpConnectionParser`.

Comment: Thank you, Marten! It's pity that you left Spring... @nabsha, you asked common question. if you were to ask <tcp-connection-factory>, I'd pointed you to the right place

Comment: Honestly I was not expecting this mapping to be hardcoded that way, so I narrowed my question scope. Thanks.